# How can I get a long list of keyworded arguments redundantly inside and outside a dictionary?

Tags: python

Is it possible to avoid rewriting all the assignments just to have the class members **also** available as a dictionary?

```
class Data(object):
    def __init__(self, X, y, z=None, U=None, v=None, w=None, p=None, q=None):
        self.X = X
        self.y = y
        self.z = z  
        self.p = p  
        self.U = U  
        self.v = v  
        self.w = w  
        self.q = q  

        self.dic['X'] = X
        self.dic['y'] = y
        self.dic['z'] = z
        # and so on...

        # and lots of functionality here and other methods...
```

Comment: Why do you need the class? Isn't a dictionary enough?

Comment: hmm you can try to give it as an argument an array and then run a forloop that will put it in that dictionary, but I have no idea why are you suing that class ... I think that dictionary is enough ... No need to refence it as different object ..

Comment: If you do `d = Data(1, 2)` and set `d.X = 5`, you will have `d.dic['X'] != d.X`. Is this what you want to happen? How are you using the `dic` attribute?

Comment: @Blender The instances are intended to be immutable and the arguments are references to arrays. So none of the cases you mentioned will happen. Additionally, __set_attr__ will be overriden to ensure immutability.

Comment: @ReutSharabani Only the init is shown.

Comment: @viyps: in that case look at the [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) module available in Python 3.7+. You can easily create a `__post_init__` method that creates a `dic` attribute with the desired contents with `dataclasses.fields` or just by using `dataclasses.asdict` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.7 or above, you should probably use [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) for this kind of thing.

Otherwise, there are two good patterns to know about. First, you can get the args passed into the function by filtering the `locals()` psuedo-dict, which we can do with a dictionary comprehension. Second, every object has a `__dict__` attribute which gives provides dictionary-like to the object's attributes. We can `update()` it to avoid writing all those `self.x = x` lines. Put this all together, and we have a very convenient way to write `__init__` methods:

```
class Fancy:

    def __init__(self, a=None, b=None, c=None, d=None):
        args = { k:v for k, v in locals().items() if k != 'self' }
        self.__dict__.update(args)
        self.dic = args.copy()
```

Absent dataclasses, this is the Pythonic idiom for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to get thier names and values from `locals()` dictionary and do the following:

```
self.dic = {}
for name, value in locals().items():
    if name != 'self':
        self.dic[name] = value
```